# Strange behaviour in HTML5 contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span that is inside a list-item.

```
<ul>
    <li>text part 1
        <span class="note">this is a note</span> 
        text part 2
    </li>
    <li>text part 3</li>
</ul>
```

On that span, i turn it to contenteditable when you double click it.

```
$('span').on('dblclick', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    this.focus();
});
```

For some reason, the focus doesn't work as it should: you don't see the cursor blinking, but if you start typing it writes on the span, adding the some text in front of it that is the rest of the li content.

Confusing? here it is in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rB8Gs/1/)  (Chrome)

If you change the event to 'click', everything works as expected.

Is this a bug? It only happens in Chrome, Firefox seems fine.
Has anyone experienced this already?

**UPDATE:** here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9dQTci4wz0) of it happening

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv i added a video

Answer (score 0):

you shouldto do that on div not a span see the correction here : 
js :

```
$('.note').on('dblclick', function(ev){
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});
```

html :

> ```
> ul>
>     <li>sdfjdslfjdlkfjsdlkjdsfl sdfh
>         <div class="note">this is a note</div> 
>         j fhdsf kfh.
>     </li>
>     <li>sdfjdslfjdlkfjsdlkjdsfl sdfh j fhdsf kfh.</li>
> </ul>
> ```

see it alive 
http://jsfiddle.net/rB8Gs/3/

Comment: @TimDown  i didn't understand you !!

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour from your fiddle. Are you using Chrome?

Comment: it's valid but not showing what he want , when i change it to div it show that thing , i don't know what its name :(

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez yes chrome

Comment: ImadOS, run your code, double-click on the note (div) and imediatly start writing

Comment: @ImadOS and if you change it to span you can see the problem i'm having?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47131/discussion-between-andre-alcada-padez-and-imados)

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez , yes

Comment: using chrome on mac, it's not happening (chrome 32)

Comment: I'm using chrome 32 on mac :(

Comment: @ImadOS i added a video

Comment: i think you mean the cursor not blinking on after double click but it does if you start typing ?

Comment: @ImadOS yes, i mean that and when you start typing some text appears out of nowhere